# How can I change URL of existing list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation, 2013, url

If I create a list with a name like `Project Risks` it gives it a url like: `http://myhost/mysite/Lists/Project%20Risks/AllItems.aspx`.

If I customize the list and *then* decide I want it call `Project Goals` how can I modify the url to something like: `http://myhost/mysite/Lists/Project%20Goals/AllItems.aspx`.

I have full site administration privileges.

I have come up empty using both the web-based design tools and the Designer 2013 tools find this option. From what I can gather from a variety of searches here and the web in general this used to be possible with previous versions of SharePoint.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this with 2013?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, or that you were able to in earlier version (I've been diggin through my 2013 and 2010 installs and can't find a thing.) You may need to save the list as a template (including content) and then make a new list using the template.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can change the URL of a SharePoint 2013 List in Designer by following the steps outlined in this SO post:

[Change SharePoint Library URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904944/change-sharepoint-library-url)

Essentially:
In SharePoint Designer just navigate to All Files navigation node (not List and Libraries node), find your list there -> right-click list -> rename.

The URI would change then.

Answer (score 7):

Using Powershall Script , change list URL.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –erroraction SilentlyContinue

$libOriginalUrl = "/Lists/YourLibName1";
$libNewUrl = "/YourLibName2";
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://....

$lib = $web.GetList($web.Url + $libOriginalUrl)
$rootFolder = $lib.RootFolder;
$rootFolder.MoveTo($web.Url + $libNewUrl)
```

Comment: this is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can rename the URL really easily. If you open up the list in Windows Explorer you can then just renmame the folder that represents the link.
In the lists themselves is no possibility to directly go to the list, however you can pass by a library to open explorer and follow the tree!